# Expanding $\langle \langle a,b \rangle b,c \rangle c$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Can I expand $\langle \langle a,b\rangle b,c\rangle c$ to $\langle a ,b \rangle \langle b,c\rangle c$. Is so, What is the formal method to do that expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner product is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Elementary_properties) in the first coordinate, it satisfies $$\langle \alpha b,c\rangle = \alpha \langle b,c\rangle$$
for any scalar $\alpha$.  In the present example, $\alpha=\langle a,b\rangle$.